# Uninstallation of Excel Addin not removed from MS Excel Addin tab/custom tab

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, excel-2010, excel-addins, ribbon-control

I have an application that is developed using CommanBar tools. As there are much constraints in that, i have planned to shift to the Ribbon(view designer). I created a project like, File->New Project->Excel 2007->Excel Addin for 2010.
Created a sample addin and added a new project to the same solution as I wanted the addin to be added using installer(.msi). I registered the Com Addin in the Registry, but on uninstallation, the files are getting removed only in the registry entry, but not in the MS Excel, the addin still to be remained there. Please help me in this. As I am new to the implementation of Ribbon implementation.
I have used winform c# 4.0.

Thanks in advance.
[image: the addin still in the MS excel addin tab]
[image: screenshot for registry entries for the .msi]
[image: registry entries in regedit]

@kiru - the screen shot for the path you mentioned
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the path from where the addins are been loaded.

1. Open Excel
2. Click File => Options => Addins (Tab)
3. Select COM Add-ins in Manage dropdown box and click Go
4. Select the addin and you can see the path where it is been loaded.

If it is from bin directory then follow this
If you are running your msi on development pc clean your solution every time you test your msi.

Comment: @kiru- what is this development PC and bin directory? I read that there is something called application manifest and deployment manifest i have no idea on this as I am new.Can you please provide the information on this?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you got problem with msi that it doesnot remove the addin. Your Excel still has got addins even after running uninstall.

Comment: Your Excel basically refers to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Addins or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Addins so you have to check these registry entries

Comment: @ Kiru, thanks, but I dont have an entry in the 15.0 created, the last version i have in mine is 14.0, and should I make the registry entry to 14.0? Not to default addin path in excel? I will add the screenshot of this again.(My addin is created in excel->TestAddin1)

Comment: @Kiru-the other screenshot is the entry is created in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->WoW3264->Software->Microsoft->Office->Excel->Addin->ExcelAddin1.Connect

Comment: Ignore 15.0 I got Office 2013, it should be 14.0 if you are using Office 2010. So when you uninstall using MSI the registry entry stays there.

Comment: @Kiru- I made an entry in 14.0 and after uninstall, the entry only goes from the regedit but not from the Excel addin tab in MS Excel.

Comment: And also clickOnce is automatically selected... :-( and previously there are no folder named "Addins" in the Excel folder for 14.0(x86).It is installed in wow3264 in local machine.

Comment: Please follow the steps given in answer above, you need to find which causes the addin to be loaded in your Excel. Also do search your whole registry for your addin and delete if not required.

Comment: @Kiru- No it dint help me after following these steps.